# Wordpress share users database for Login

Tags: database, wordpress, authentication, sites

What i'm trying to do is to share the users credentials between 2 or more Wordpress installations on the same database. I read many tutorials, and forums on this one but none gave me a clear answer on this one. So according to Wordpress Codex ([1]), all I have to do is add the code below to wp-config.php (child installation) in order to switch tables for users and usermeta:

```
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'main_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'main_usermeta' );
```

This allows me to login with the root sites' username and password but I'm getting the message

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Then I'm completely lost. I checked the _capabilities inside the database as stated at [1] but still getting that message.

Any help would be really appreciated since I'm working on this one for 3 days. Thanks!

[1] http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite the right way to go about it. If you succeed with this, I think you'd be opening yourself up to some serious security vulnerabilities.

Instead, you should look into creating a WordPress Multisite install. The details of Multisite are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

You can also learn more about Multisite here: http://mashable.com/2012/07/26/beginner-guide-wordpress-multisite/

Trying to get two separate installs to share information isn't the normal way to attack this problem... most of the times with this requirement, I've seen people use Multisite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply!! It seems that this is the proper way to do what I want. I already created the network, added both root and child sites. What I need is: when someone registers to the root site, then this user won't have to register again at the child(sub-site) site. From what I read this is possible with Networks but I have to find the way to do this.

Comment: Tried this one but even though in the network users it shows that the user is register at both sites, I still cannot login to the sub site(registered from main site). Also in the backend of sub site, the user doesn't appear. It's weird because during installation of network I didn't have to add anything to sub site's wp-config.

Comment: Wait....in a multisite network, you only have one WordPress install and one wp-config... I'm not sure if the "I didn't have to add anything to the sub site's wp-config" means that this was configured incorrectly... but to be clear, just in case, setting this up with one WordPress install that's Multisite and importing the theme and content of the second site.... is that what you did?

Comment: Actually I connected to sites. The main one was the main site and the other one was a subfolder, so I had 2 wp-config.php files. What I meant is that during the setup of the network, I didn't have to change anything in the sub site's wp-config.php. So I don't think that the if you register from the main site, the user is automatically registered in the sub site. For anyone trying to do the same, I bought a plugin for 20$ which connects 2 sites and if someone registers from the main site, he is automatically registered at all the sub sites. The link is: http://goo.gl/gPgG16

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

Our goal is to set up two WordPress websites which will share logins and the same users. Once a user has subscribed one

website, she would be able to access the other website with the same role and capabilities.

**step 1:** In order to share the same users and usermeta tables, WordPress installations must share the same database.
add prefix of first wordpress installation first_ and second wordpress installation table second_. in same database.

**step 2:** When the first WordPress website is up and running, we can edit its configuration file. Open /first/wp-config.php

and add the following lines above the ‘stop editing’ comment:

```
 $table_prefix  = 'first_';
 define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
 @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );  

// custom users and usermeta tables
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix . 'usermeta' ); 

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

**step 3:** We are done with the first installation. Next we have to copy wp-config.php from the first installation folder and

paste it into the root folder of the second installation. Be careful to change the $table_prefix value accordingly:

open /second/wp-config.php.and add the following lines above the ‘stop editing’ comment:

```
 $table_prefix  = 'second_';
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
    @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

      // custom users and usermeta tables
     define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'first_users' );
     define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'first_usermeta' );
```

**step 4:** write in both wp-config.php for sharing cookies.

```
    //Share cookies
   define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.xyz.com');
   define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');
```

**step 5:** Open table "first_usermeta" and copy from column meta_key - first_capabilities and first_user_level to the second_capabilities and second_user_level.
[image]

**step 6:** When running the second installation, we should set a non-existent email address for admin user as WordPress finds a number of existing users from first_users table.

For more Detail [https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/.](https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/)

It's work for Me.