# WordPress: Share Users Table across 2 DB's

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I Have 2 very high traffic WordPress sites that I need to share logins and user meta between the two. Both sites will need the ability to update the user meta tables as we do gamification style transactions.

The two sites do not share the same tables or the same database. They do share the same DB server.  [I've seen examples where people define custom DB tables and rewire the cookies.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634430/wordpress-share-users-database-for-login) What I cannot understand is how that actually works...because they don't redefine the sql user or the selected database just for that table. And I don't know if that will work for me anyway because both will require the ability to update_user_meta(); and make calls to read it and reflect on both sites.

I cant use multi-site due to issues with caching in this high traffic environment.

Comment: "I cant use multi-site due to issues with caching in this high traffic environment." I have to call you out on this excuse. How does using multi-site have **anything** to do with caching?

Comment: Multisite is very finicky and alien when it comes to caching.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make one of the websites use the other's database. Make sure you back-up your databases and website files before you do this.

You have to change the database prefix of Site1 in wp-config.php and then copy the login information from Site2's wp-config.php. After you do that, the Wordpress will take you trough the installation process (but don't worry, your folders on the server won't get deleted). Once you finish with the installation, you will have to export Site1's old database and import it into Site2's database (make sure that Site1 is using the same prefix in it's old database as well on Site1's database).

By doing this, you have migrated Site1 on Site2's database with all it's data and now you will be able to define custom user tables and rewire the cookies as you saw in that example. There might me other ways to migrate one website with all it's data to a new database, but this is the way I have done it and it worked well for me.